# Multiple Output paths for a C# Project file

Tags: c#, build-process

Can I use multiple output paths. like when i build my project, the exe should generate in two different paths. If so, How can I specify in Project Properties-> Build -> output path? I tried using , and ; but neither of those work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a section `build events` in your project's properties. You can use `post-build events`to copy your output to different locations. Just press 'Edit Post-build' and 'Macros', so that you can even use shortcuts to your output directory. For more informations have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

Comment: brief: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9675235

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. But you can copy the exe file to another directory after the build. In the "project options"->"Build Events"->"Post-build event command line" you can add a copy command. There are several placeholder available (like the output dir). Just check the "Edit post-build" button.