# is there any way to reflect the changes in dll among the systems use it without many steps

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll

Q:

I have a `dll` which used in many systems, when i make any modification in that dll ,i have to build it, copy this dll ,paste it in the `bin folder` of each web application module, and add a reference to the new one.

**Is there any way to reduce the number of these steps?** , i mean , is there any way to make any modifications to this dll visible in all systems with out all these steps.

**EDIT:**

the `GAC` will solve my problem if the applications at the same host ,but to be more clear , we use a source control to modify classes and more than one can modify this dll , what i want is: when i make any change to that dll , this doesn't force me to copy it through the bin folders of my applications.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/chrismoseley/archive/2008/10/28/shared-assemblies-without-the-gac.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059118/reference-dlls-in-asp-net-without-bin-or-gac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this assembly as [Shared Assembly](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/shared-assembly.html), and install it in the `GAC folder` and reference this assembly in `each application from GAC folder`

Comment: thanks a lot ,but I'm confused, can u please provide more explanation how to do it, or a link to explain the steps.

Comment: @just_name; check this article http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/shared-assembly.html

Comment: when i type `sn -k` in the command prompt i get the error `isn't recognized as internal or external command`.

Comment: is this command prompot of Windows or Visual Studio ? it should be Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, I have read the your edit part and I face the same situation. What I did is, Like I have one project library that is source safe, I always add the project library from that reference from source, so in the case every one can modify and if some one modify, other one can get latest version and rebuild, it will get changes.

Comment: In summarize My point is, Get Shared project from Source safe in every project.

Comment: hmmmm, excuse me still not clear.I have dll and this dll used in many projects , every time i change this dll i have to copy it in bin folder of each application.is the alternative is web service for example , i don't know?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin`
in visual studio 2008 command prompt. it works

Answer (score 1):

Use shared assembly if possible or if you want to still continue with private assembly then create a batch file which will copy the dll to all the desired location if your multiple web application is running on the same server

steps to create shared assembly 
http://www.vkinfotek.com/assemblyhowto.html
http://www.dnzone.com/go?698

Answer (score 1):

The [global assembly cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) stores assemblies specifically designated to be shared by several applications on the computer.

Refer to [How to install an assembly into the Global Assembly Cache in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808).

**Edit:**

Refer to [Multiple Output paths for a C# Project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795565/multiple-output-paths-for-a-c-project-file).

Comment: thanks , but what is the relation between my question and this link?i'm confused ,please can u explain more?