# Multiple output paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I set up the VS so that it **outputs the dll to multiple directories**?

Comment: Are you planning to enter code here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VS post build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to copy the generated dlls.

something like:

```
copy $(TargetPath) new/path/to/dll/mydll.dll
```

Comment: can you please specify what i can mention on new/path/to/dll/mydll.dll

Comment: This is where you want to copy the DLL to, this is a standard DOS copy command.

Answer (score 2):

I got this when i use

```
 xcopy /Q /Y "$(TargetPath)" "C:\path\to\somewhere\"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your project properties there is a Build Events section. You can use the post-build events to output your DLL's to different locations.